# How can I send an image over a socket from C# to Python?

Tags: python, c#, sockets, unity-game-engine, tcp

I'm trying to take an image from the camera on my phone and send it to a Python server using sockets. I convert the image to bytes using EncodePNG() and then I add generate a header for my buffer to tell the server how large the body of the buffer will be.

On the client:

```
byte[] body = tex.EncodeToPNG(); // tex is the texture I convert to PNG
byte[] header = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(body.Length.ToString().PadLeft(6, '0'));
byte[] buff = new byte[body.Length + header.Length];

header.CopyTo(buff, 0);
body.CopyTo(buff, header.Length);
                    
stream.BeginWrite(buff, 0, buff.Length, null, null);
```

On the Python server I'm receiving the header, getting the body length, and then attempting to receive the image data.

```
    headerBytes = client.recv(6)
    bodyLen = int(headerBytes.decode('utf-8'))


    e = 0
    data = ''
    while e < bodyLen:
        d = str(client.recv(size))
        e += len(d)
        data += d
        
     nparr = np.fromstring(data, np.uint8)
     frame = cv2.imdecode(nparr, cv2.IMREAD_ANYCOLOR)
     cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
```

I get an exception `OpenCV(4.5.3) C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-85db8uu_\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'` which seems to be an error with the image data.

I've been at this for a while now and tried everything I could find in other answers, would appreciate being pointed in the right direction! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Seems like OpenCV imshow needs the image in BGR, so you can try to convert it from RGB to BGR first.

```
...
frameGBR = cv2.cvtColor(frame , cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
cv2.imshow('frame', frameGBR)
```